# transfer table values into another table using onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

i need help guys i want to know how to transfer a table row value into another table row using onclick already know how to get the value using the onclick but dont know how to transfer the values into the table

```
    <html>

    <body>
    <table class='list'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='idno'>ID No.</th>
        <th class='itemn'>Item</th>
        <th class='quant'>Quantity</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chocolate</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
    target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
    var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
    }
    }
    alert(data);
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create some nodes. Create a `<tr>` first. Then loop the following: create a `<td>`, then a text node from the data that you have already collected, append the text into the `<td>` then the `<td>` into the `<tr>` and repeat the loop. Finally append the `<tr>` to the table body. Run the code snippet below.

```html
<html>

    <body>
    <table class='list'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='idno'>ID No.</th>
        <th class='itemn'>Item</th>
        <th class='quant'>Quantity</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chocolate</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

      <br><br>
      MY NEW TABLE
      <table class='list'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='idno'>ID No.</th>
        <th class='itemn'>Item</th>
        <th class='quant'>Quantity</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id='myNewTableBody'></tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        tbody.onclick = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            var data = [];
            var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
            while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
                target = target.parentNode;
            }
            if (target) {
                var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
                for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                    data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
            var trnode = document.createElement("tr");
          
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var tdnode = document.createElement("td");
                var textnode = document.createTextNode(data[i]);
                tdnode.appendChild(textnode);
                trnode.appendChild(tdnode);
            }
          
            document.getElementById("myNewTableBody").appendChild(trnode);
            alert(data);
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code, look into this

```js
 var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  
  // get other table you want to insert in
  var t2 =document.getElementById("othertable");
  
        tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
    target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
    var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
 
 //insert at zero index
 var tr = t2.insertRow(0)
 
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
  

  var cell = tr.insertCell(i);
  cell.innerHTML = cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
    }
    alert(data);
    };
```

```html
    <table class='list'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class='idno'>ID No.</th>
        <th class='itemn'>Item</th>
        <th class='quant'>Quantity</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Chocolate</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Bread</td>
        <td>99</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
 <hr/>
<table id="othertable"></table>
```